# firebase authentication timeout

Tags: android, timeout, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an Android App with Firebase. The login process with email and password is working fine if the device has a good internet connection, but when i make a test in a bad signal place or with a slow connection, the process stay waiting a lot of time. the question is: exists some way to set a timeout for firebase authentication?, the delay is not good for the user experience. I solved this with a Asynctask released on click login button event, this Asynctask waits eight seconds and shows an Alert to user with the message: the connection is slow, you can wait or exit and try it later, but i think so the best way is with a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Sure com.google.android.gms.tasks package should not be obfuscated and well documented by google in the future. I solved the same problem by running my task with synchronous awaiting it on current thread by using utility method 'await':

```
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks;

private String requestToken(boolean refresh) {
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    Task<GetTokenResult> task = user.getIdToken(refresh); 
    return Tasks.await(task, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

In case when internet connection is bad, await method will throw java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException after specified timeout